# Parse XML response to another requests in Postman

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, postman

I must to test a few webservices who response in XML format and i want to parse the response from first request to second request call.

Ex: **I make a first request**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:exec>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:sName>55</ser:sName>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <ser:sArguments>{{Param1}}</ser:sArguments>
         <ser:sArguments>XX</ser:sArguments>
         <ser:sArguments>POSTMAN</ser:sArguments>
         <ser:sArguments></ser:sArguments>
         </ser:exec>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**who response with:**

```
<soap:Body>
        <ns2:execResponse xmlns:ns4="http://address.com" xmlns:ns3="http://services" xmlns:ns2="http://services.com">
            <ns2:execReturn>6666&#xd;
</ns2:execReturn>
        </ns2:execResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And i want to put 6666 in a GlobalVariable or EnvironmentVariable to use in second request call.

**What i try untill now:**

First i set a parameter(NumberReq) in Manage Environments - GLOBALS then in TESTS i put this code:

```
var jsonData = xml2Json(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("NumberReq", jsonData.execReturn);
```

And in the next request i try to use the NumberReq param like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.com">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ser:exec>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <ser:sName>99</ser:sName>
             <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
             <ser:sArguments>00</ser:sArguments>
             <ser:sArguments>{{NumberReq}}</ser:sArguments>
             <ser:sArguments>{{Param2}}</ser:sArguments>
             <ser:sArguments>{{Param3}}</ser:sArguments>
             </ser:exec>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have a collection with this two webservices and i run from Postman Runner, but don't work to parse the response.

Can anyone help me? 
Thx! :)

Comment: Is the problem that the value is not set to the variable or that it's not taken from it?

Comment: I think the value is not set to the variable, i put a console.log("PARAM: " + jsonData.execReturn); and it's display: PARAM: execMRPCReturn is not defined.

Comment: I'll try to make it for you.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The trick is how your XML is converted to JSON and how to access JSON data.

Your parsed JSON has the next structure: 
[image]
So in order to get a value from it you should get elements step by step like this:

```
jsonData["xs:schema"]["xs:element"][0]["$"]["name"]
```

So to set up the variable you need to do this:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("NumberReq", jsonData["soap:Body"]["ns2:execResponse"]["ns2:execReturn"]);
```

Hope that example above is exactly the code you need. If not, revise the structure of the parced JSON and change the way to the element you need.

Probably you also can do it using "dot" structure, like `jsonData.Body.execResponse.execReturn`

Comment: Thank you! :)
 
Ít's working now, i use this:

`postman.setEnvironmentVariable("NumberReq", jsonData["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["ns2:execResponse"]["ns2:execReturn"]);`

You now if i can use regular expression to extract something from Response, my reponse is: 123456789012TX00TEXT0000123456789012 and i want to extract the first 12 digits or the last 12 digits. 

my regex is: "(\w{2})(\d{2})(\w{4})(\d{4})(\d{12})" but i don't now how to use in postman, but, this is another question. Thank you! :)

Comment: It work the regular expression, i use this:

`var regularExpression = /^.{0,12}/; \n
var text = jsonData["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["ns2:execResponse"]["ns2:execReturn"];

match = regularExpression.exec(text);`

Answer (score 7):

I was able to come up with a slightly easier solution for reading from the xml response.

```
var xmlTree = xml2Json(responseBody);
var text = xmlTree["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"]["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["ns1:loginResponse"]["loginReturn"]["_"];
var textstring = JSON.stringify(text);
console.log(textstring);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("loginReturn", textstring);
```

### Here is the response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:loginResponse>
            <loginReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">b1c705515532a9abc353b32e91de3b97</loginReturn>
        </ns1:loginResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

### HOWEVER, I am not able to utilize the variable I saved to Environment in subsequent request using the following format

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:shoppingCartCreate soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">{{loginReturn}}</sessionId>
         <storeId xsi:type="xsd:string">1</storeId>
      </urn:shoppingCartCreate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: In Pre-request Script put:

`postman.getGlobalVariable("loginReturn");`

Hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

It works the regular expression, i use this:

```
var regularExpression = /^.{0,12}/;
var text = jsonData["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["ns2:execResponse"]["ns2:execReturn"];

match = regularExpression.exec(text);
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This function convert the XML String into JSON object using regex.

```
function xmlStringToJSON(xml, primaryTag = 'response') {
    if (!xml) return {};
    const regex = new RegExp(`<${primaryTag}.*[^>]>((?:.*\n)*(?=<\/${primaryTag}>))`, 'gmi');
    xml = regex.exec(xml)[1].replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
        .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
        .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
        .replace(/&quot;/g, "\"")
        .replace(/&#039;/g, "'")
        .replace(/\t/g, '')
    if (!xml) return {};
    if (xml.indexOf('<?xml') > -1) xml = xml
        .replace(xml.slice(xml.indexOf('<?xml'), xml.indexOf('?>') + 2), '');
    xml = xml.split('\n').filter(itm => !!itm.trim());
    return (function recursiveParse(lines, currentLine = 0, object = {}, parent = null) {
        if (currentLine === lines.length) return object;
        const line = lines[currentLine],
            openTag = line.match(/<([^\/\s>]+)(\s|>)+/),
            closeTag = line.match(/<\/([^\s>]+)(\s|>)+/),
            tagContent = line.match(/(?<=>)(.+)(?=<\/)/);
        currentLine++;
        if (!tagContent && openTag && !closeTag)
            object[openTag[1]] = recursiveParse(lines, currentLine, {}, object);
        else if (tagContent && openTag && closeTag) {
            object[openTag[1]] = tagContent[0];
            recursiveParse(lines, currentLine, object, parent);
        } else if (!tagContent && !openTag && closeTag)
            recursiveParse(lines, currentLine, parent);
        return object;
    })(xml);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?