# parse XML response by name not by index in postman

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, postman

As from this [Parse XML response to another requests in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812012/parse-xml-response-to-another-requests-in-postman)

[image]

So in order to get a value from it we should get elements step by step like this:

```
jsonData["xs:schema"]["xs:element"][0]["$"]["name"]

jsonData["xs:schema"]["xs:element"] [1]["$"]["name"]

jsonData["xs:schema"]["xs:element"][2]["$"]["name"]
```

we are getting `name:"Envelope"` field by index `0,1,2`
Is there any way to get the field `name:"Envelope"` directly by name not by index? Using the index to verify presence is a bit fragile. Should I rather check for the presence of simple field `"Envelope"` in schema no matter its position?

I have to find if the name Envelope is present or not and need to find if it contains any values.

Answer (score 0):

By using `substr` you can get directly that field and from there you can parse xml:

```js
pm.test("body has field", function(){
    var response = pm.response.text();
    var responseBody = response.substr(response.indexOf('name:"Envelope"'));
    var responseJson = xml2Json(responseBody);   
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).